# Uninstalled a module, but only one part of the module is deleted, not the entire in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I had a module called as View Slideshow installed from the website -
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

which had two modules automatically installed-

Views slideshow module and Views Slideshow: Cycle module.

Then, I uninstalled only one module for some reason --> Views Slideshow:Cycle. And View Slideshow module has not been uninstalled.  Now i want to use both. But View Slideshow : Cycle module doesn't come as a separate installation. How to deal with such an issue ?

Neither View Slideshow is getting uninstalled , nor View Slideshow: Cycle as a separate module is getting installed. I am stuck up.

Comment: Check .info files to see mutual dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I solved it . I went to the path sites/siteurl/modules/views_slideshow and deleted the folder. I did it through filezilla as the drupal portal is uploaded on the server.